# How do I remove .sparsebundle files in my home folder from being excluded by Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine

I have a problem in that any `.sparsebundle` I create in my home folder tree is not getting backed up to time machine.

It is like an 'exclude by path' but I can't remove it or see where it is defined.

```
# whoami
root
# tmutil isexcluded /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle /Users/Administrator/atest.sparsebundle
[Excluded]  /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle
[Included]  /Users/Administrator/atest.sparsebundle
# defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist ExcludeByPath
(
    "//Users/Shared/adi",
    "/Users/Shared/adi",
    "/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/PlayReady"
)
# ls -l@ /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 0 18 Oct 20:54 /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle
# xattr -l /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle
# rm /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle
# tmutil isexcluded /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle
[Excluded] /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just stumbled on this. There is another list of standard Exclusions in `/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist`. Mine doesn't mention sparsebundle files though. Might be worth checking that file on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the exclusion with the `tmutil` command?

> tmutil removeexclusion /Users/andy/atest.sparsebundle

Comment: Yes I have tried that many times.  I think it is an exclusion with a named path somewhere because the `tmutil isexcluded` shows that any name (a file that doesn't even exist) is excluded if the name matches *.sparsebundle There is one file I have that matches that search that does get backed up, but any new ones I create don't

Comment: Is it perhaps intentional? Is the system perhaps designed to only backup the contents of a sparsebundle when it is mounted?